# What's LazyList?

Tags: android, lazylist

I can't find in any really credible source explaining what LazyList is. Anyone?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Lazy List** is lazy loading of images from sd-card or from server using urls. It is like on demand loading of images.

Images can be cached to a local sd-card or your phone's memory. URL is considered the key. If the key is present in the sd-card, images get displayed from sd-card, otherwise it downloads the image from the server and caches it to a location of your choice. You can set a cache limit. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

Instead of the user waiting to download large images and then displaying them, lazy list loads images on demand. Since images are cached, you can display images offline.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Lazy List

In your getview

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageurl, imageview);
```

ImageLoader Display method

```
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) //url and imageview as parameters
    {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);   //get image from cache using url as key
    if(bitmap!=null)         //if image exists
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //display iamge
     else   //downlaod image and dispaly. add to cache.
     {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
     }
   }
```

An alternative to Lazy List is Universal Image Loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. It is based on Lazy List (it works on the same principle), but it has lot of other configurations. I would prefer to use ****Universal Image Loader**** because it gives you more configuration options. It can display an error image if a download failed.  It can display images with rounded corners. It can cache on disc or memory. It can compress an image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
  File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
 imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
          // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
         .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
         .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
         .enableLogging()
         .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
.build();
```

In your getView()

```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
  imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options
```

You can configure Universal Image Loader with other options to suit your needs.

Along with LazyList/Universal Image Loader you can view this website for smooth scrolling and performance.
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

Comment: Hey raghu,i am unable to fetch images from local uri can you help please??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109034/lazy-list-fetching-images-from-sdcard-local-url

Comment: great explanation, so Lazy list is similar to picasso or glide?

Comment: @user2198400 those are image caching libraries. Yes they help in lazy loading.  Also do read about listview recycling mechanism.

Comment: appreciate your fast answer, is there any example on using lazy list with picasso or glide? thanks in advance

Comment: @user2198400 search for chessemaster in github from Chris banes

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, I'll explain you with the example 
If you list contain lot of images with Text, it will take some time for your list to load because you need to download images and you need to populate them in the list. Suppose if your list contains 100 images It will take lot of time to download each image and to show it the listitem. To make the user wait until the images loads is not user friendly.
so What we need to do. At this point of time lazy list comes into picture. It is the idea that let the images be loaded in background and show text mean while.

Everybody know that listview recycle its views for every view. i.e if your listview contains 40 elemtns then listview won't allocate memory for 40 items instead it allocate memory for the visible items, i.e say you can see only 10 items at a time. so listview will allocate 10 items meemory.

So When ever you scroll the view, then the view will refresh. because of the you'll lose your reference to images and you need to download them agian. in order to avoid that, caching comes into picture.

This example is based on my knowledge in listview, I am not saying this is only correct. There might be wrong in the answer, if any body find feel free to inform me.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the other way around. AFAIK, [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) is the definition, where you actually load the data only when you need it, and it's a good design practice.

So I believe the same applies for this, only this time it's being referring to the List View.

If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

The best example of lazy list is facebook notifications,messages,requests. when you scroll then data will be load.