# (beginner) How do I load images off of a site via main url address with lazy list?

Tags: android, url, imageview, lazylist

I'm trying to find a way to load all of the images off of sites main page(that uses an image slider) into an imageview/listview(much like the damnlol app). On my last question I asked a similar question and never got an answer I could actually use. I was told to use lazylist and use something from this question [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview) , But I have absolutely no idea how to implement ether of those things as I am completely new to android programming. I cant be given a random piece of code and know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these links:

**[Lazy loading images from urls to listviews](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/lazy-loading-images-from-urls-to-listviews/)**

**[Whats lazylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist)**

**[Android development tutorial: Asynchronous lazy-loading and caching of listview images](http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/)**

After these you can return here and ask questions that have risen from trial and error with **CODE EXAMPLES**.

Comment: Before, I start these tutorials. I have to explain. My app needs to be able to load the Image url's from the main sites image slider, and it needs to be able to update them whenever new images are added to the site. Will these tutorials help me design an app that can accomplish those things?

Comment: They will help you to get on the right track. If you are asking me if they will provide you with copy/paste ready code then the answer is: maybe not.

Comment: I wasn't, I wanted to know if they provided the kind of help I need.

Comment: They do. Just read through them. Be patient and you'll be up and running in no time!

Answer (score 0):

Loading the images from the Url, you can achieve this using Coil lib, whereas for lazylist + images example you can refer to this article I Wrote for tech beginners to help. https://medium.com/p/cb42e1d021cf

Comment: are you the author of that medium article?

Comment: yes I try to write. You can ask if there's any issue

Comment: please expand your answer post. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587. Also, you _must_ disclose in your post that you are affiliated with the linked resource. see any [/help/promotion](/help/promotion). Go back to your older answers posts on Stack Overflow and do the same.

Comment: thanks for the references I will take care.