# Android ListView with Image and Text; can't display ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I am trying to display ListView with Image and text,I have used Simpleadapter class,But I am unable to display ListView Could any one help me,what i did wrong?

Here My Code:

```
public class HostsActivity extends ListActivity {
    public final static String ITEM_TITLE = "title";
    public final static String ITEM_IMAGE = "Image";
    private List<HostsProfile> hostsProfile1;
    List<Map<String, ?>> security = new LinkedList<Map<String, ?>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hostslist);

        Bundle recdData = getIntent().getExtras();

        hostsProfile1 = recdData.getParcelableArrayList("hostsProfile");

        List<Map<String, ?>> security1 = new LinkedList<Map<String, ?>>();
        for (HostsProfile msg1 : hostsProfile1) {
            // Log.v("image","Image path"+msg.getImage());
            try {
                URL url = new URL(msg1.getMediathumbnail());
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                security.add(createItem(msg1.getTitle(), img));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
        /*for(int i=0; i<security.size(); i++){
            security.remove(0);
        }
        */
        SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, security1,
                R.layout.image_text_layout1, new String[] { ITEM_IMAGE,
                        ITEM_TITLE }, new int[] { R.id.feed_image,
                        R.id.job_text });
        adapter1.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
        this.setListAdapter(adapter1);
    }

    public Map<String, ?> createItem(String title, Bitmap Image) {
        Map<String, Object> item = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        item.put(ITEM_TITLE, title);
        item.put(ITEM_IMAGE, Image);
        return item;
    }
    //for ImageView
    class MyViewBinder implements ViewBinder {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                String textRepresentation) {
            if ((view instanceof ImageView) & (data instanceof Bitmap)) {
                ImageView image1 = (ImageView) view;
                Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data;
                image1.setImageBitmap(bm);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here are my layout xml files:

image_text_layout1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/feed_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp" 
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/job_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <!--android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="28dip" 
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip" />-->

</LinearLayout>
```

hostslist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">

        </ListView>  

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a `CustomListview` project:

CustomListView.java

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class CustomListView extends Activity {
    ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    ContactImageAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // add image and text in arraylist
        imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.facebook, "FaceBook"));
        imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.google, "Google"));
        imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.ical, "Ical"));
        imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.outlook, "Outlook"));
        imageArry.add(new Contact(R.drawable.twitter, "Twitter"));
        // add data in contact image adapter
        adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.list, imageArry);
        ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        dataList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Contact.java

```
package com.example.customlistview;
public class Contact
{
    int image;
    String name;

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Contact(int image, String name) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ContactImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.customlistview;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
    Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;
   ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
   public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;
       this.data = data;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       ImageHolder holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
           holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       Contact myImage = data.get(position);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
       int outImage=myImage.image;
       holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(outImage);
      return row;

   }

   static class ImageHolder
   {
       ImageView imgIcon;
       TextView txtTitle;
   }
}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.55" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" ><ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.71"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Put icon in drwable, which is used in the main activity image array.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to you to use a custom listview with a custom adapter.

An example is available at the link below.

[android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Use a viewholder for smooth scrolling and performance.

You can also use lazy list or universal image loader.

Both use caching.

[Lazy List and Universal Image Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist/15622374#15622374.)

Check the below links for viewholder and loading bitmaps efficiently

[Listview smooth scrolling using ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.)

[The world of Listview talk by android developers at google](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70.) The talk is about viewholder and list view performance.

[Loading bitmaps efficiently from developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). Load bitmaps efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

add Class For Lazy Loading FileCache.java

========

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

=========ImageLoader.java

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
               memoryCache.clear();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

======MemoryCache.java

```
public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache=Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));//Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private long size=0;//current allocated size
    private long limit=1000000;//max memory in bytes

    public MemoryCache(){
        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){
        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

=====Utils.java

```
public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

====ContactImageAdapte.java

```
public class ContactImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{
Context context;
   int layoutResourceId;   
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
   ArrayList<Contact> data=new ArrayList<Contact>();
   public ContactImageAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Contact> data) {
       super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
       this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
       this.context = context;
       this.data = data;
     this.imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View row = convertView;
       ImageHolder holder = null;

       if(row == null)
       {
           LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
           row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

           holder = new ImageHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
           holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
           row.setTag(holder);
       }
       else
       {
           holder = (ImageHolder)row.getTag();
       }

       Contact myImage = data.get(position);
       holder.txtTitle.setText(myImage.name);
          int outImage=myImage.image;
      imageLoader.DisplayImage(listres.ItemImage,holder.ItamImage);
      return row;

   }

   static class ImageHolder
   {
       ImageView imgIcon;
       TextView txtTitle;
   }
}
```

=====try This