# How to load pictures with text in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I        have       100       items,        all       have       an     image     and       some    description,    i have a `ListView` and i want to open  the items with `ListView`, so how do i do that ? i want to show description and image for each item. do i need 101 activities?

Comment: You can just use two Activities, one to display the list and other to display detail. Use intent to transfer info about which item was clicked.

Comment: No use only one extra activity, everytime u click listview item change the content of that activity.

Comment: @Keshav how do i do that?

Comment: Pass id of selected Item in Next Activity and get Data using that id

Comment: In which form you have 100 Items, please post some code or briefly explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You Can Use Listview With Image And Text Using List Adpter Here I Send You Link See My Answer Step By Step U Follw it.[Listview With Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984220/android-listview-with-image-and-text-cant-display-listview/15987830#15987830)

Comment: wait i give you link and before i send u link plz tel me u have to laod image from drwable or url

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ see this example

Comment: one more thing, what resolutions of images should i use

Comment: why are there three packages in that example? can i put the 3 class files in one package?

Comment: One is main activty,second is adpter and third one is for your listview row

Comment: so i need all the packages?

Comment: Thats for good code readability. You can put them in one package.

Answer (score -1):

[Fedor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95313/fedor)'s [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) is simple and very efficient, and loads the images from a URL, but I could also modify it to load images from resources folder.

Comment: that is also possible with this code. I did it offline only. Little alteration is needed. The code is very efficient. Since you load 100 images, so u need to take care of memory. With this it is possible

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

Comment: but i see three packages in the example, can i put the three class files in one package instead?

Comment: ya u can put this three class in one package and ya u have to compulsury take three clas

Answer (score -2):

No, you only need one activity and one `Fragment`. Each time you click one item in the ListView, call [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) and update your fragment. I think that should be method that helps you refresh its content view . Or you can create a new one (not best solution)

Comment: need one adapter class and main activity then add adpter to listview . for more information check this link :- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: @user2968888 what do you mean? you really understand the question?