# Progressbar in each gridview item Android

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar

I have a gridview showing images and progress bar. Each item contains progress bar and it shows progress when corresponding file downloads. While scrolling gridview, progress bar repeatedly shows progress in wrong items and i am using a viewholder. Please give me a solution...

Comment: Post your Code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `ProgressBar` objects are getting reused arbitrarily by the system when they scroll offscreen.

This means that when one `ProgressBar` scrolls offscreen, it is reused in a new grid position as that item appears.

The solution is fairly easy. In `getView()` you must set the progress value and the visibility (if you are hiding them when not in use) of each `ProgressBar` irregardless of the state of the download. In order to do this, you will have the progress value and download state for each grid position saved, which you probably already have available.

Comment: Thanks David... i got solution from your answer. Can u suggest any idea to show progress while downloading... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Here is an example that shows how to download and update a `ProgressBar` while incrementally reading the data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog. This example is good even if you are not using `AsyncTask` to manage your download. The important part is to update your `ProgressBar` inside the `while(input.read())` loop.

Comment: For me, the difficulty is how to upgrade the progress value. Because the notifyDataSetChanged will update all cells which apparently is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
     vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowimage, null);

    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.ivv); 
    ProgressBar pb= (ProgressBar)vi.findViewById(R.id.pb); 
    display(image, data.get(position).toString(), pb);
    //imageLoader.displayImage(data.get(position).toString(), image,options);

    return vi;
}

  public void display(ImageView img, String url, final ProgressBar spinner)
   {
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, img, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
         spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

});
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivv"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    />
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

In your adapter constructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "UniversalImageLoader/Cache");


 // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
   imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
 // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
              // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
             .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 1024, CompressFormat.PNG, 100)
             .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
             .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
             .enableLogging()
             .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
    //imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(a));
   // imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .cacheInMemory()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
    .build();
```

I have used the above with Universal Image Loader. A stub Image is displayed along with progress dialog at the center. Once Image is downloaded. Image is set to imageview and progress dialog disappears.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

[What's LazyList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist/15622374#15622374).

You can see the resulting snap shot. I have used the above for listview. It should be the same for gridview as well. For testing purpose i have used a default launcher image. But can remove the stud image, customize your progress dialog.

[image]