# Image is loading every time in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am fetching images from URL. I use AsyncTask to display images. But images reload each time when I scroll up and down.

Here is my code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.useryouramourstlist, null,
            true);

    final ImageView userprofilepic = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.userprofilepic);

    try
    {

        new ImageLoader().execute(view, +URL+listArrphoto[position]);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }

    return view;
}


public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Bitmap> {

    private View view;
    private Bitmap bm = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... parameters) {

        // Get the passed arguments here
        view = (View) parameters[0];
        String uri = (String)parameters[1];


        bm = loadImageFromUrl(uri);

        return bm;
        //return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null && view != null) {
            ImageView albumArt = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userprofilepic);
            albumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}

public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {

    Bitmap bm;
    try {  

            URL aURL = new URL(url);  
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 

            conn.connect();  
            InputStream is = null;
            try
            {
             is= conn.getInputStream();  
            }catch(IOException e)
            {
                 return null;
            }

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);  

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);

            bis.close();  
            is.close();  

       } catch (IOException e) {  
        return null;
       }  

    return  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,60,60,true);


}
```

Comment: you need to cache images if want to avoid downloading it everytime. Use LazyList of universal image loader. Check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist

Comment: But Why images load every time when scroll up and down. If I used without AsyncTask then Its not load again and again when scroll up or down

Comment: you might be calling asynctask in your getview.

Comment: can you say me how to do that ?

Comment: how to use lazy list or UIL check the link in the 1st comment. It caches images in sccard or phone memory. If already present , displat from cache else download cache and display

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option, though could be costly on memory depending on your list size, is on your `ImageView` after loading the image call `view.setTag(bitmap)`, and before you attempt to fetch the image, do a sanity check.

```
if(view.getTag() != null) {
    view.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)view.getTag());
} else {
    new ImageLoader().execute(view, +URL+listArrphoto[position]);
}
```

Of course, I would opt for downloading to the applications cache directory and loading from the file if it exists.

Comment: You can also try storing it into a Map<String, Bitmap> where the key is the url and the value is the Bitmap.  Again, I would not recommend this for large lists.