# Universal Image Loader with URLs from JSON

Tags: android, json, gridview, universal-image-loader

I am pulling 4 different items from JSON and storing them in a `Map` and would like to take one of those items (and `img` URL) and use that in the Universal Image Adapter `GridView` option. Is this possible?

The example on GitHub utilizes a static `String` of URLs which in my case will not work for me. My JSON look is in my `onPostExecute`

```
for(int i=0;i<_results.length();i++){   

                    JSONObject s = _results.getJSONObject(i);
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(2);

                    String myIMG = s.getString("images");
                    String quotes = myIMG.replaceAll("\"", "");
                    String slashes = quotes.replaceAll("\\\\", "");                 
                    String myIMG2 = slashes.split("url:")[1];
                    String myIMG3 = myIMG2.split(",height")[0];
                    String pinner = s.getString("pinner");
                    String pinnerQuotes = pinner.replaceAll("\"", "");
                    String curly = pinnerQuotes.replaceAll("\\}", "");
                    String pinnerName = curly.split("full_name:")[1];

                    map.put("desc", s.getString("description"));
                    map.put("img",  myIMG3);
                    map.put("url", s.getString("link"));
                    map.put("name", pinnerName);

                    _pinData.add(map);
```

So after this point I somehow need to take `myIMG3` and use that in the Universal Image Loader GridView. However, I still need the rest of that info so I can pass it through an onClick to a detailed view that utilizes all of that info for that specific image. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: add all urls ie myIMG3 in a list then use a UIL or Lazy list to display the images. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist. pulling items from json can be done using asynctask

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for the reply. If I do it like this, then I lose the other info that I need to pass to a detail page. Unless I am missing something?