# drawable for bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-drawable

I'm facing an **OutOfMemory Error** on my application.. the reason is I have lots of images loaded on my application..So upon researching for possible solutions, I found this link and downloaded the whole sample project
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

I find it related to my problem only that it loads the images online which is in my case, all the images in my application can be found on **drawables**..

So my question is, is it possible to use the images from my **drawables** rather than loading it from specific URL. If it is, please kindly give me a very simple sample of it....

I'm really having a hard time on this since Im new to android development and Im just relying on tutorials online.. thanks

Here is what I am talking about...

```
   public class Images {

/**
 * This are PicasaWeb URLs and could potentially change. Ideally the PicasaWeb API should be
 * used to fetch the URLs.
 *
 * Credit to Romain Guy for the photos:
 * http://www.curious-creature.org/
 * https://plus.google.com/109538161516040592207/about
 * http://www.flickr.com/photos/romainguy
 */
public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s1024/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s1024/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s1024/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s1024/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s1024/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
// more …
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-e9NHZ5k5MSs/URqvMIBZjtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/1fV810rDNfQ/s1024/Yosemite%252520Tree.jpg",
};

/**
 * This are PicasaWeb thumbnail URLs and could potentially change. Ideally the PicasaWeb API
 * should be used to fetch the URLs.
 *
 * Credit to Romain Guy for the photos:
 * http://www.curious-creature.org/
 * https://plus.google.com/109538161516040592207/about
 * http://www.flickr.com/photos/romainguy
 */
public final static String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[] {
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s160-c/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s160-c/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s160-c/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s160-c/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
// … more 
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-e9NHZ5k5MSs/URqvMIBZjtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/1fV810rDNfQ/s160-c/Yosemite%252520Tree.jpg",
};
 }
```

**Note**:  this code was the sample provided on this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Im sorry if my explanation is not clear enough, feel free to ask me for follow up question... thanks

Comment: you should know that an Intent memory is size is few bits so you should process images and load their thumbs instead.

Answer (score 2):

you should not cache so much images in your memory. There is a good library made by [nostra](http://nostra13android.blogspot.in/).

Library : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Try to implement library. This provides memory as well hard caching which will not let  your application force close due to memory.

Answer (score 0):

It is better you download and display images when you need instead of having so many images in drawable folder.

You should display btimaps efficiently. Load a scale down version in memory

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Also check Managing bitmaps memory in the below link

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html.

If you run into memory leaks use a Mat Analyzer to find and fix the same

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

If your displaying images from url consider using lazy loading technique

[What's LazyList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist)

[Caching images and displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789676/caching-images-and-displaying/16978285#16978285)