# ImageView Android Memory

Tags: android, memory-management, imageview

How can I build an array of ImageView which will be initialize once and when I would want to draw an image on the screen I simply call that card on the specific position? I am building a blackjack application and for some reason when I'm trying to use photos that consist more than 200 kilobyte it runs slow, but with photos that consists 30 bytes it's fine!
So I thought if I will store all the photos on the program instead withdrawal than each time it will save memory, right?

Comment: The file size is not relevant.  I can make a 25kb PNG which needs more RAM than a 1mb PNG easily.  What size are the images?

Answer (score 0):

Images can be cached to local sd-card or phone memory. Url is considered the key. If the key is present in sd-card, display images from sd-card else display image by downloading from server and cache the same to location of your choice. The cache limit can set. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

[For more information visit link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621936/whats-lazylist)

```
holder.ImgArticlePhoto = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.img_ArticlePhoto); 
Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (holder.ImgArticlePhoto,item.Image);
```

Comment: OK Thanks, but I didn't get where should I write that code in my project..?

Comment: At the point where the loaded image, or where SET picture doing.                    Code in edit comm

Comment: I can't understand that :(.. I'm a beginner !

Comment: Where are you set your Image add code : ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context);
...
imageLoader.DisplayImage(url, imageView);

Comment: I'm using other method - imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image); to set the card each time a player draw...

Comment: Ok for set, but my code cache your image i no every time get(URLimage) good for memory and speed app

Comment: Yeah I know it's good for memory but I don't understand how to do it :(

Comment: Create variable ImageView myImage = new ImageView; and add code Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (myImage,R.drawable.image);